# Проблема при отправке POST запроса через HttpClient

Tags: .net, https, httpclient

Возникла проблема при отправке POST запроса к API через HttpClient.
Есть код:

```
private Task<TOut> PostAsync<TIn, TOut>(Uri baseUri, string requestUri, TIn input, string token = null)
        {
            return HttpRequestAsync<TOut>(c => c.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(baseUri, requestUri), input), token);
        }

        private Task<TOut> HttpRequestAsync<TOut>(Func<HttpClient, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> httpRequest, string token = null)
        {
            return HttpRequestAsync(httpRequest, r => r.Content.ReadAsAsync<TOut>(), token);
        }

        private async Task<TOut> HttpRequestAsync<TOut>(Func<HttpClient, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> httpRequest, Func<HttpResponseMessage, Task<TOut>> httpResponse, string token = null)
        {
            using (var client = CreateHttpClient(token))
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = await httpRequest(client);
                    using (response)
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                        {
                            throw new NotAuthorizedException();
                        }

                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        {
                            throw new NotFoundException
                            {
                                AnswerStatusCode = response.StatusCode,
                                AnswerReasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase
                            };
                        }

                        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound &&
                            response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("Ошибка сервера сервиса маркировки");
                        }

                        var result = await httpResponse(response);
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                catch (NotAuthorizedException)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                catch (NotFoundException)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Ошибка запроса к системе", e);
                }
            }
        }

        private HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
        {
            return new HttpClient();
        }

        private HttpClient CreateHttpClient(string token)
        {
            var client = CreateHttpClient();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            return client;
        }

        private HttpClient CreateHttpClient(Dictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            var client = CreateHttpClient();
            if (headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            }

            return client;
        }

        public async Task<long> SendRegistrationRequest(IsmpBaseRequestModel<RegistrationRequest> request, string token)
        {
            try
            {
                var uri = new Uri(@"https://int01.gismt.crpt.tech/api/v3/true-api");
                var method = "elk/registration";

                var res = await PostAsync<IsmpBaseRequestModel<RegistrationRequest>, RegistrationResponse>(uri, method, request, token);
                return res.RequestId;
            }
            catch (NotAuthorizedException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ошибка авторизации в ГИС МТ", ex);
            }
            catch (NotFoundException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ресурс не найден", ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ошибка отправки запроса на регистрацию в ГИС МТ", ex);
            }
        }
```

В ответ сервер присылает 401 статус и ошибку "Cannot convert access token to JSON". JWT токен формируется правильно, потому что при отправке запроса из Fiddler или Postman всё хорошо, статус 200 + ожидаемый ответ.

Пробовал прикреплять сертификат к HttpClient, ничего не выходит. Еще заметил, что в Fiddler не отображается заголовок Authorization Bearer {access_token}, в то время как в запросе из Postman этот заголовок есть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал использовать HttpWebRequest вместо HttpClient? Не знаю как это работает, но в разных ситуациях у меня работали разные способы.